# Jquery opacity slider. Working, but crude

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I've wrote a code for simple jquery slider, it's working, but code is ugly. Can anybode suggest improvements?

```
 $j(function() {
  $j('.single-slide:gt(0)').css({opacity: 0.0 });
  $j('.single-slide:first').addClass( "current-slide" );
  $j('.single-slide:last').addClass( "last-slide" );
  setInterval(function() {

    if ( $j( '.current-slide' ).hasClass( 'last-slide' ) ) {
      $j( '.last-slide' ).removeClass( 'current-slide' ).fadeTo( 'slow', 0 );
      $j('.single-slide:first').addClass( "current-slide" ).fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );
      return;
    } 
      $j( '.current-slide' ).fadeTo( 'slow', 0 ).removeClass( 'current-slide' ).next().fadeTo( 'slow', 1 ).addClass( 'current-slide' );

  }, 3000)
});
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place for code review. Please check [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MarkusEgle Don't see any reason why not in link that you provide

Comment: @MarkusEagle it's a perfectly normal stackoverflow question.

Comment: In my opinion not perfectly normal. ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your HTML looks like, but yes, the improvement is not to use jQuery (or JavaScript for that matter) at all.

CSS these days now has neat ways to use animations and transitions... You can do something like this using animations and keyframe functions:

```
.slide-in {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Or something like this using transition:

```
.last-slide {
    opacity: 0;    
}

.slide-in {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 2.0s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The only JavaScript you will need is adding/removing classnames to begin the animation/transition.

These CSS features work on all modern browsers now.